# Сортировка векторов через функцию sort

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector

У меня вопрос  связанный с сортировкой.

У меня есть 2 структуры:

```
struct Exam {
    string subject;
    int numQuestions;
    vector<int> correctAnswers;
};

struct Student {
    int id;
    string name;
    vector<Exam> exams;
    double averageGrade;
};
```

И объявляю их через вектора

```
vector<Exam> exams;
vector<Student> students;
```

Прошу заметить что в структуре `Student` дополнительно объявлен массив `Exam`.

#### **В чём сам вопрос**

Когда я сделаю сортировку

```
sort(exams.begin(), exams.end(),correctSort);
```

все нормально
но если я делаю сортировку в

```
 for (const auto& student : students)
    {
        sort(student.exams.begin(), student.exams.end(),correctSort);
    }
```

она сыпется, почему так и как это исправить

```
bool correctSort(const Exam& a, const Exam& b) {
    return a.subject < b.subject;
}
```

Comment: а как сортировать константный вектор ? уберите const `for (auto& student : students)`

Comment: спасибо, совсем забыл об этом